# Is there any way to pro-grammatically create product categories and assign thumbnails in PHP and WooCommerce?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I want to create categories and assign a thumbnail to them.

wp_insert_term can't be used for what I am asking, and I wonder if there is any other way known to man.

I have seen the other question on the community but it doesn't seem to work when you actually use it. I don't know why it is marked as correct.

Comment: Since this question is tagged "woocommerce," do you mean WooCommerce "product categories" or do you mean post "categories" or do you mean any kind of "category"? Do you want to assign and edit images from category edit, or do you want to assign an image or images programmatically to categories? Where are they supposed to appear on the front end once "assigned"? (Yes, there are ways known to humankind - including in plug-ins.)

Comment: @CKMacLeod I mean product categories. I want to assign thumbnails programmaticaly. I want them to appear at the front end once assigned.

Answer (score 1):

`wp_insert_term()` works fine for this sort of thing.

You haven't given any context, but here's a quick example I made that, on every page load, adds a random WooCommerce product category(not duplicates though), and an associated random image, from a list of image id's in **MY** media library(change `$existing_image_ids` to your own ids for this to work).

```
// page load creates a random product category, and an associated image
add_action( 'init', 'rand_product_cat_w_rand_image' );
function rand_product_cat_w_rand_image() {

    $test_product_cats = [
        'Test Category 1',
        'Test Category 2',
        'Test Category 3',
        'Test Category 4',
        'Test Category 5'
    ];

    $existing_image_ids = [
        '144',
        '143',
        '142',
        '141',
        '140'
    ];

    $rand_cat = rand( 0, 4 );
    $rand_img = rand( 0, 4 );

    $new_cat_title = $test_product_cats[$rand_cat]; // title of product category
    $new_img_id = $existing_image_ids[$rand_img]; // id of image you want to use from your media library

    $new_cat_added = wp_insert_term( $new_cat_title, 'product_cat' ); // 'product_cat' is woocommerce product category taxonomy, and were adding a new category with title

    if(is_wp_error( $new_cat_added )) {
        return; // there was an error adding new product category, usually because it already exists with only 5 available test categories
    }
    else {
        add_term_meta( $new_cat_added['term_id'], 'thumbnail_id', $new_img_id, true ); // add image to new product category, etc.
    }    
}

// This bit is just copied from WooCommerce docs for showing product category image:
// REF: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-display-category-image-on-category-archive/
add_action( 'woocommerce_archive_description', 'woocommerce_category_image', 2 );
function woocommerce_category_image() {
    if ( is_product_category() ){
        global $wp_query;
        $cat = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
        $thumbnail_id = get_woocommerce_term_meta( $cat->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true );
        $image = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumbnail_id );
        if ( $image ) {
            echo '<img src="' . $image . '" alt="' . $cat->name . '" />';
        }
    }
}
```

Tested and works.